# can we update an instance related to a foreignkey django signls

Tags: python, django, signals

hi i want to update an instance related to a foreignkey value

for example i have these two models

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    cash = models.IntegerField()
    qnt = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def product_loan(self):
        return (self.price * self.qnt ) - self.cash

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    balance= models.IntegerField()
```

i want to whenever an instance from `Collection` been created then update balance in `Company` i tried this django signal but doesnt seem to work

```
def post_save_collection(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.company_name.balance =instance.company_name.balance +((instance.price * instance.qnt) - instance.cash)
        #and also tried this but not worked 
        #instance.company_name.balance = instance.product_loan
post_save.connect(post_save_collection,sender=Collection)
```

is there something i've missed please? or should i change something else ?

Comment: The modeling does not seem to make much sense. A company can have *multiple* `Collection`s, since it is a `ForeignKey`, this thus means that the last saved collection will determine the *balance* of a `Company`?

Comment: Furthermore usually it is better not to store aggregates in models, but just calculate the aggregate "*on the fly*". So use `annotate(..)` on `Company` when you need it.

Comment: yes , a Company can have multiple Collection , yes i want it

Comment: thanks for your advice , its not the entire project ,but how to update the balance ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem isnt there a solution please

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if you have an idea please let me know

Answer (score 0):

i had to use `update`

```
def post_save_collection(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Company.objects.filter(name=instance.company_name).update(
        balance=F('balance')+instance.product_loan
           )
post_save.connect(post_save_collection,sender=Collection)
```